# RS232 concurrent communication

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, rs232

I need to interface with a printer equipped with a RS232 port from both my arduino microcontroller and my computer. It means that the printer is connected to the computer through the RS232 port and I would like to connect an arduino card to the same RS232 port in order to send some commands.
Which is the best design to put in place this solution?

Comment: "Which is the best design to put in place a switch or another solution is such a way..." I don't understand what you are asking. Switch?

Comment: Huh?  What are you trying to switch?  Nothing is guaranteed to never fail.  How failure-secure does it need to be compared to a ordinary connection?  Extra high reliability will be a protocol matter once the basic electrical connection is made.

Comment: The question asks how to multiplex the atmega328's single uart peripheral between the USB serial converter which connects it to the PC, and another serial device.  But this may not be the best solution to the ultimate goal.

Comment: sorry everybody, the question was badly written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hackers' way to do it, assuming cabling is short and ignoring the possibility or the severity of conflict between Arduino and the PC, would be to connect Tx lines over diodes + resistor circuits. Their Rx lines can be spliced together with no worries, and connected to printer's Tx line.

The goal is to allow each RS232 port's MARK (positive voltage) level to override other port's SPACE (negative voltage) level and vice versa, but OTOH to keep the SPACE level present on the line when both of Tx's are silent.

That means that each Tx line should be connected to joint line by two parallel branches: first, a diode with anode on Tx output and cathode on line (printer's Rx) and second, a diode and resistor in series, oriented the other way around - cathode towards Tx, anode towards printer's Rx. I can't tell you the resistance value from the top of my head, I would start with 10K, but if you have trouble with serial communication speed, try substituting smaller ones until it works.

I hope I was clear, but here is attempt of ASCII art schematic, copy it and paste into ASCII editor with fixed width font:

PC Tx -------+---------------+
             |                          |
             +----[Resistor]-+
                                        |
                                        +---------- Printer Rx
                                        |
Arduino Tx --+---------------+
             |                          |
             +----[Resistor]-+

Answer (score 0):

It depends what Arduino platform you are using.
But it should have at least a second UART module that you can use. 
You can use a chip such as MAX232 to do the conversion RS232 <-> UART
And that's it. You have two RS232 on your arduino that can work at the same time.

Comment: The Atmega328 on the primary Arduino platform has only one UART, though software implementations on the GPIO pins are possible at limited baud rates.  Many alternate platforms, likely included the Arduino Mega and the new Arm-based board, as well as those from other vendors, might have more hardware UARTs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a simple printer (text + some control codes) consider hanging the printer off the Arduino's I/Os using the software serial library and an RS232 level translator such as the MAX232 or descendants.  Set the printer for a baud rate within the allowable range of soft serial.

Then have the PC talk to the Arduino's USB-serial, thinking that it is the printer itself, using the same baud rate.  Have a sketch on the Arduino which copies characters between the two serial connections, except when the Arduino decides to insert its own commands.

It probably will have to block traffic from the PC while inserting its own commands.